# Foreach loop through results from array items from current month

Tags: php, json, foreach

Fixed it.

I am trying to get a table to show me the results of items sold in the current month. And create a sum of the total value

```
$currentMonth = date('m');

//Loop through data
foreach($data[$i] AS $api)
{   
    if ($data[$i]['date_created'] = $currentMonth)
    {   
        $orders[$i]['id'] = $data[$i]['id'];
        $orders[$i]['status'] = $data[$i]['status'];        
        $orders[$i]['date_created'] = $data[$i]['date_created'];
        $orders[$i]['total'] = $data[$i]['total'];
    }
    $i++;

    $sum += $data[$i]['total'];         
}
```

Right now i get all the results dating back to November last year.

What i try to achieve is only the results for this current month, so let's say August 2019.

Hope you guys can help me

Thanks all for the input, I should indeed make $api calls, however my array starts direct at 0 and the json results start showing then in this form:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19778
            [date_created] => 2019-08-20T20:06:29
            [status] => processing
            [total] => 207.00
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19704
            [date_created] => 2019-08-19T17:53:56
            [status] => processing
            [total] => 18.50
        )
```

I can foreach all the results, however now I want to filter based on the current month.

I have a separate table in HTML which does the for calls:

```
<? for($order_out = 0; $order_out < count($orders); $order_out++):
    $order_client = $order_out + 1; ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$order_client?></td> 
        <td><?=strftime("%d-%m-%Y" ,strtotime($orders[$order_out]['date_created']))?></td>                                          
        <td><?=$orders[$order_out]['id']?></a></td>                                         
        <td><?=$orders[$order_out]['status']?></td>                                             
        <td><?=$orders[$order_out]['total']?></td>                                              
    </tr>       
<? endfor; ?>
```

Comment: `$data[$i]['date_created'] = $currentMonth` is no comparison, it's an assignment. `==` or `===` are comparisons.

Comment: I hope @LLJ97 answer helps you. But my doubt is, why you are incrementing $i inside foreach loop.

Comment: @MuhammedShihabudeenLabbaA is right about that. You increment and you don't use `$api` variable therefore the foreach loop is basically pointless. You wrote it like a for loop.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you add a small sample of the array

Comment: `$api` ?? Why are you not using that SOMEWHERE. What is the point of the loop if you dont use that.

Comment: I'm more confused about "date_created" if that really is month only. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Show us an example of the contents of `$data` and show us where and how `$i` is created and manipulated please

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that too. Looks like a Cluster Typo to me

Comment: Ha! Cluster typo. That's a good one.

Comment: Added additional info, my date returns as the following:
2019-08-20T20:06:29

Comment: Just do as we ask you, add a sample of the array. As the question is now it should be closed because it's unclear

Comment: @andreas Done, added more info to the original question

Comment: added the total item, as this was further down the line in the json output. I am indeed new to SO.

Comment: Have you replaced the `foreach` code with the `for` loop code, or is this other code you are now including in your question

Comment: it is added code, as i am trying to map variables to the returned json results. Which work with other projects that do not include a filter based on the current month.

Comment: This is the first time you mention JSON? where does thsi come from

Comment: JSON was in my initial request, thanks all for the input, I will continue with finding a solution. @RiggsFolly I never had an issue with my script until now as i started filtering date based results. i will try some more versions to match a timestamp.

Comment: I fixed it by converting $currentmonth = date('m') to $currentMonth = date('m', strtotime('now'));

And did the same for date_created
if (date('m', strtotime($api['date_created'])) == $currentmonth)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've made a few mistake here.

1.

```
if ($data[$i]['date_created'] = $currentMonth)
```

You assign `$data[$i]['date_created']` to `$currentMonth` instead of comparing these two variables.

It's the same operation as `$a = $b` which always returns `true` (assignment is successful).

So basically what this line does:

```
if(true) { 
  $data[$i]['date_created'] = currentMonth;
  // rest of code
}
```

Try changing this line to

```
if ($data[$i]['date_created'] === $currentMonth)
```

2. You `foreach` is not really correct. You are using `for` approach. Iterating `$i` inside of the loop and not using iterated element `$api`.

Assuming that your `$data` and `$orders` share the same keys, then your code could look like this:

```
$currentMonth = date('m');
$sum = 0; // have some initial value

//Loop through data
foreach($data[$i] AS $i => $api)
{   
    if ($api['date_created'] === $currentMonth)
    {   
        $orders[$i]['id'] = $api['id'];
        $orders[$i]['status'] = $api['status'];        
        $orders[$i]['date_created'] = $api['date_created'];
        $orders[$i]['total'] = $api['total'];
    }

    $sum += $api['total'];         
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$currentMonth = date('m');

//Loop through data
foreach($data AS $api)
{   
    $month_date_created = date("m",strtotime($api['date_created']));
    if ($month_date_created == $currentMonth)
    {   
        $orders['id'] = $api['id'];
        $orders['status'] = $api['status'];        
        $orders['date_created'] = $api['date_created'];
        $orders['total'] = $api['total'];
    }
    $order_out[] = $orders;
    $sum += $api['total'];         
}
```

In the foreach loop you can get array of array as well.

Comment: Why is OP editing the answer here?

Comment: @ml88, Now, In this answer, where you are checking the condition?

Comment: You are STILL ignoring the date comparison issue i.e. `2019-08-20T20:06:29` WILL NEVER `==` `date('m')` which will be `08`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, this answer was written initially as per his first question. In that his main problem was because of not using == for condition check.

Comment: This looks like it is becoming a `RABBIT HOLE` question. i.e. no end to the changes and new requirements. BEWARE

Comment: @RiggsFolly In that case, thanks for your downvote. It really encourages

Comment: You can make it a useful answer, I think, if you add the date comparison fix

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I have added the method to check month

Answer (score -2):

First issue is you are using single "=" in if condition.

Secondly your date_created variable may contain d/m/y. so extract the month and year part from the date_created and compare it with current_date = date('m/y') to get the August 2019 records only.